# NACA Airfoil Matlab questions

Tags: matlab

I got an obstacle in generating an NACA Airfoil graph. Here is the code:

```
% NACA 6414%
clc
clear
format compact

m1=input('Please enter one digit number for maxi camber line:')
p1=input('Please enter one digit number for distance of m and chordline:')
t1=input('Please enter two digit number for thickness of airfoil:')

m=m1*0.01;
p=p1*0.1;
t=t1*0.01;

x1=[0:0.01:p];
x2=[p:0.01:1];
x=[x1,x2]


yc1=(m*(2*p*x1-x1.^2))/(p^2);
yc2=(m/(1-p)^2)*((1-2*p)+2*p*x2-x2.^2);
yt=(t/0.2)*(0.2969*sqrt(x)-0.1260*x-0.3516*x.^2+0.2843*x.^3-0.1015*x.^4)

yc=[yc1,yc2]

ang1=(atan((m/p^2)*(2*p-2*x1)))*180/pi
ang2=(atan((m/(1-p)^2)*(2*p-2*x2)))*180/pi
ang=[ang1,ang2]

xu=x-yt.*sin(ang)
yu=yc+yt.*cos(ang)
xl=x+yt.*sin(ang)
yl=yc-yt.*cos(ang)

xplot=[xu,xl]
yplot=[yu,yl]

plot(xplot,yplot)
```

Instead of generating an normal airfoil graph, it comes with an very weird graph which contains many circles on the picture. Can any one help me figure out how to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem, I suspect:

```
 ang1=(atan((m/p^2)*(2*p-2*x1)))*180/pi
 ang2=(atan((m/(1-p)^2)*(2*p-2*x2)))*180/pi
 ang=[ang1,ang2]

 xu=x-yt.*sin(ang)
 yu=yc+yt.*cos(ang)
 xl=x+yt.*sin(ang)
 yl=yc-yt.*cos(ang)
```

The functions sin and cos expect an input in radians.  The output of atan is also in radians, but you're converting it to degrees, which means that the output in xu, yu, etc, which you later plot will be wrong. Try to avoid conversion unless you really need the angles in degrees.  Alternatively, you could use the other forms of these functions (sind, cosd, atand, etc) and keep everything in degrees throughout.